# What is the difference between Arrays, Linked-lists and Stacks?

Tags: data-structures

I'm currently learning the fundamentals of Algorithms and Data Structures and I am slightly confused about the concepts and the differences between arrays, linked-lists and stacks.

Please correct me if I am wrong: Is stack more like an abstract concept, and arrays and linked-lists are data structures? (Hence we can use either arrays or linked-lists to implement the concept of stack)

**Update - 032221**

Thank you everyone for helping me out for this question! Back when I asked this question, I had a hard time understanding the overall concept of primitive data types and fundamental data structure (in this case an array) that is offered by each languages.

For example, linked list or queues can be created and implemented using array, but then I thought such linked list and queues still should be called as array (because the foundational data structure that is used behind is technically an array). My thought process was there would be primitive data structures for linked lists or queues that does not use an array. Thus I did not understand quite properly linked-lists or stacks or such data structures are just different patterns and ways that data is organized and configured.

I hope this can help anyone who is having a hard time understanding data structure concept like I did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Programming Theory perspective all the tree are **Abstract Data Types** The fundamental differences between them are their features.

- Array - offers a random access to any element in constant time, but removing or adding an element from/into an array is done in linear time
- Linked List - offers random access in linear time (that means sequential access). But adding or removing an element is done in constant time.
- Stack is a little bit different. It offers you access only to a single element - the top of the stack. The same is valid to removing and adding an element. You can remove only the element that is on the top of the stack and vice versa, add new element on the top of the stack.

You are correct that the stack can be **implemented** using array or linked list but this is already an implementation point of view. From Theory perspective they are different Abstract Data Types.

In fact if you dig deep enough on the assembly language level you have only 2 options to locate an arbitrary element:

1. Indexing - Calculate the element location in memory
2. Indirect addressing - Using a pointer stored in memory to locate the element.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The concept of ADTs definitely helped me understand :) Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**Array**

A book is an array. You can go to any page by index and quickly go forwards or backwards by any increment you like.

**Linked List**

A scavenger hunt is a linked list. You can only go from one item to the next, because each item contains the information where to find the next item.

**Stack**

A pile of letters on your desk is a stack. You can only see the letter lying on top. Removing the top letter reveals the next letter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I was confused because if those three are all data structures, why would you specially have to 'implement' for stack using array or linked-list (It felt as if you are building a data structure using a data structure).

Comment: I think it clicked with me with this post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148747/abstract-data-type-and-data-structure?noredirect=1&lq=1 Thanks for your answers too :)

Comment: @WillKim The implementation really depends on the context, architecture, platform, language etc. For example your CPU uses a stack for instructions, and it's a very real thing. If you have to implement a stack like object/structure in a high-level programming language, then yes, you'd usually use some kind of array or list as basis. Again this depends on the language, some languages don't allow for easy list implementations (think BASIC), and some languages don't have real arrays (think Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

**ARRAY** - a container that can be called a fixed number of items and those items should be of the same type.

**STACK** - a list of elements in which an element may be added or deleted only at one end called the top of the stack.

**LINKEDLIST** - a linear collection of data elements called a node pointing to the next node by means of a pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!